# Can I find a structure with certain size in c source?

Tags: c, gdb, sizeof, coredump

I'm trying to debug one core dump (mainly using gdb) and all I found out so far, is that that there is a structure of exactly 124 bytes, that is causing problems. Given all the sources of this program, is there a way to find that structure? (I mean is there a way to find structure, whose size is 124 bytes)

- PS. I know exact place in memory of this structure, yet there is no
  clue about it's purpose if I look at it. It is also common structure,
  so I can make as many core dumps as I wish.
- PS2. So far I tried:

  1. to use regular expression `grep '^ *[a-zA-Z][^ ;,."()]* [a-zA-Z][^
     ;,."()]*' * | grep -v 'return' | sed 's/[^:]*: *\([^ ]*\).*/\1/' |
     sort | uniq > tmp.txt` , add `p sizeof(x)`  to each found line and
     input to gdb.
  2. to use `info variables` in gdb, log output, extract variable types
     and add sizeof(x) to each type and output to gdb.

Comment: Can't you get the point in source where it is crashing and inspect the code to see which structure is being used in that function or the calling function etc?

Comment: I can't because core was generated by manually by abort. By faulty structure I mean that there was 1000000 of such structures allocated (which is 1000 times more than usual). This is the reason it was manually aborted.

Comment: Checking if I understood correctly: You need to find the _type_ of the structure, right?

Comment: I'd inspect a few of the structures in the dump and see if you can determine their layout. Any character strings in them, for instance?

Comment: I mentioned that in first PS. Unfortunately there is no characters, and most of the other bytes are random. Also, there is too much code in program for this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a header file which is included by all the source file, define a macro,

```
#define malloc(size) my_malloc(size, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

And then in the implementation:

```
#undef malloc
void * my_malloc(size_t size, const char* file, int line)
{
    //if the size equal to 124 bytes, log it, then you will have a chance know where this kind of allocation happens, so you know the struct.
    if(124==size) printf(...);

    return malloc(size);
}
```

Comment: 1. you forget about calloc etc. 2. this variant is good when you can recompile code and reproduce bug condition.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this:

```
objdump -W <elf-name> | grep -B 2 "DW_AT_byte_size   : 124"
```

This command dump all debugging symbols in the ELF file and find those size is 124.

Comment: It found some data, but how do I get structure name from it?

Comment: DW_AT_name: field value in output show name of the structure.

Comment: It seems filename and line-number of the structure declaration can be extracted with DW_AT_decl_file and DW_AT_decl_line (if you specify -B 3 -A 3 in grep args you see more)